# Silent Facebook app request to specific facebook user

Tags: facebook

I'm using this code:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: "An invite',
        title: 'App Request',
        to: intFB_ID
    }, requestCallback);
```

..but when I run it, it brings up a confirmation request dialoge box, which I have to physically click to 'Send Request'.

Is there anyway to send an App Request silently, in that there is no confirmation required, and so can be run on a Cron or as a batch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you provided sends a "user generated request" and there's no way to do that without that specific dialog, so no you can not do it with no confirmation on the user side.

What you can do how ever is send an "app generated request" for the user instead.
The end result will be different though.
The two options are described in the [Social Channels doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) (under the *Requests* section).

Comment: Ah, thanks - I can't use the 'app generated request' as the user hasn't yet authorized the app - in fact the only reason I want to send a silent request is to remind them of that!

Is there anyway I could remind them about the request remembering they haven't yet authorized the app?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you let users interact with your app without authorizing it? Can you please elaborate more on your situation?

Comment: No, a user invites their fb friends with a user generated request, using the multi friend select dialoge. I just wanted to be able re-invite those who hadn't respoded to the request.

Comment: Ohhhh. Then no, you can't do that, what you described pretty much boils down to spamming. Maybe the user just decided to ignore the request?

Comment: There would only have been one reminder as I know sometimes, fb notifications can sometimes get lost amongst a host of other notifications. If it's  not possible, then it's not possible! 

Thanks anyway!